# I am unable to resolve configuration with compilerPath "gcc". what should I do

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, mingw

Unable to resolve configuration with compilerPath "gcc".  Using "C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe" instead.

Comment: Is this via command line or in an IDE? What is wrong with using the full path?

Answer (score 0):

Set setting  "C_Cpp.loggingLevel": "Debug"  and you could see more details in "C/C++" logs.